# Pseudo class :focus doesn't propagate, now what?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Question: How do I get this to work for tabbing, using CSS only? (Tabbing already works).

```css
#menu:before {
  content:"Menu \25bc";
  font-weight:bold;
  width:100%;
}
#menu:hover:before {
  content:"Menu \25b2";
}
#menu li {
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
}
#menu:hover li {
  position:relative;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <title>Test</title>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="#header1">Link to homepage</a>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#menu1">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu2">Menu item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <p>Other text with maybe a <a href="#main1">link here</a>.</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Original question follows.

I have a menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, I want to hide it at a narrow page width, so I apply the following CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu:before {
    content:"Menu \25bc";
  }
  #menu:hover:before {
    content:"Menu \25b2";
  }
  #menu a {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
  }
  #menu:hover a {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
  }
}
```

This hides the menu, adds the word "Menu" in it's place, with a down or up arrow, depending on the hover state, which also shows the menu when you hover over it.

The problem is that, while :hover works just fine, I cannot get both to show by tabbing to one of the  tags, using the :focus pseudo class. (Alas, :root will not work like other pseudo classes, so something like #menu a:focus:root #menu a { position:relative; left:0; } won't work, as far as I can see).

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could approach this, using only CSS? Or have I dug myself into a hole?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Done. As you can see, hovering over the Menu text works fine. Even though you can still tab to the links, I cannot make it show on the page. I've included links above and below the Menu, so you can check your tabbing. Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: you may give it a shot using [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget) but you may need to change your html

Comment: I'm happy to change the HTML, but how would :target work here?

Comment: Please ignore the properties in the href attributes. They are there just to help people see which element they have tagged to in the status bar. On my page, they are URLs to other pages. The problem, is that tabbing to one <a> tag inside the #menu does not show the whole menu, like when you hover over "Menu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP comment below:

> I'm happy to change the HTML, but how would :target work here?

**here is a snippet with** [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget)

```css
nav {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
nav:target {
  height: auto;
}
nav + div a:before {
  content: "Menu \25bc";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}
nav:target + div a:before {
  content: "Menu \25b2";
}
nav:target + div .open,
nav + div .close {
  display: none;
}
nav:target + div .close,
nav + div .open {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu item 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div>
  <a class="open" href="#menu"></a>
  <a class="close" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer, even though it is not tabbable. Thank you.

Comment: I can tab it perfectly..if you mean hitting the `tab` key

Comment: Sorry, I meant "hover". The tabbing works fine. My apologies.

Comment: well the `:target`replaces the `:hover`in this case